# Excel error when recording a macro in my personal workbook

Tags: windows-7

I've been trying to record a macro in my personal workbook but i keep getting this error.  "personal macro workbook in the startup folder must stay open for recording."

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might have closed it during a previous macro operation.

In any case, you can go to: 
C:\Users\{yourusername}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART 
and find spreadsheet PERSONAL.XLSB, and open that, to get rid of the message.

When you do that, and you next try to use the "Macros" features, you might get the error: 
"Cannot edit a macro on a hidden workbook.  Unhide the workbook using the Unhide command." That unhide command is under the "View" ribbon, "Window" panel.

That PERSONAL.XLSB spreadsheet stays open for you to store macros in "Personal Macro Workbook," so they'll be available in any spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Is your macro trying to close something? What actions are you trying to record? Also, have you tried recording the macro to the open workbook rather than the personal one? It is easy to move later.